# Optimize with in condition in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Team,

I need to optimize below query, please suggest best way to optimize this query. I tried with change of conditions order and even created indexes on columns.Nothing worked out for me, please post your suggestions.

FYI, iemail_id is an integer with index on both table. Below query returns 4million records.Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT T.AId, M.iemail_id
FROM tasks T WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN tmail M WITH(NOLOCK)
ON T.iemail_id = M.iemail_id
WHERE ((status IN (5,6,8,9,14,15,21,22,23,24))
OR (status =7 AND T.lmodif >= '11-19-2012 00:00:00'))
AND (Ctype='Auto')
AND (Aitem in ('DATA', 'FILE'))
AND (T.lmodif >= '08-20-2012 00:00:00' AND M.mtime <= '11-28-2012 05:25:25')
```

Comment: How many records in each of the tables? What's the query plan look like? How long does it take to run now? What indexes have been created?

Comment: Why are you using `WITH(NOLOCK)` for? `When this option is in effect, it is possible to read an uncommitted transaction or a set of pages that are rolled back in the middle of a read. Dirty reads are possible`

Comment: @Kaf This query will run on huge DB with 40 million records, we use NOLOCK intentionally this is an OLTP DB, without NOLOCK the query execution time is double than the current time.

Comment: @ElectricLlama tasks table has 20890072 records and tmail table has 20949472 records.Tasks table has clustered index on Aid and Non Clustered index on iemail_id,lmodif,status and few others.In tmail table iemail_id has clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `lmodif` and `mtime` columns are `DATETIME`, try converting your strings to `DATETIME` first. Something like `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-11-28 05:25:25', 120)`

I don’t see much opportunities for optimization in `((status IN (5,6,8,9,14,15,21,22,23,24))
OR (status =7 AND T.lmodif >= '11-19-2012 00:00:00')`. You could still try to replace it with:

```
(status BETWEEN 5 AND 9
 OR status IN (14, 15)
 OR status BETWEEN 21 AND 24)
AND (status <> 7 OR T.lmodif >= '11-19-2012 00:00:00')
```

but to be honest I doubt it will change anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this did not worked for me.I believe something need to be optimized with the condition ((status IN (5,6,8,9,14,15,21,22,23,24))
OR (status =7 AND T.lmodif >= '11-19-2012 00:00:00')).

Comment: What makes you think that? The only thing that will give you a clue is the query plan. Press CTRL-L whilst in SQL Server Management Studio and see if it recommends any indexes, also see of you can identify any piece of the query plan that contributes a large cost (percentage)

Comment: @ElectricLlama I have created Non Clustered indexes on mtime in tmail table and ctype,lmodif,aitem in tasks table.This will not effect any change in query execution time, IN condition is expensive as it needs to check all records with those statues.